# Can't serve Angular 6 on Windows 10

Tags: angular, windows, windows-10, angular6, angular-cli

I'm having a problem serving an Angular 6 project in a PC with Windows 10.
I have the Angular CLI installed with version 11.2.18 and the ng command works, but when running `ng serve` it throws this error about an RxJs operator:

`Cannot find module '../operators/refCount'`

I have no problem running `npm install` and I can serve the project without problems in a Mac with the same CLI version.

These are the dependencies of the project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "material-tooltip": "1.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "3.0.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "6.7.0",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",
    "xlsx": "0.14.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
```

Any ideas of what's wrong?

Comment: Cloning the repository and installing it again resolved the issue, which i don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install rxjs@6.2.2 --save-dev`.

Comment: Apparently cloning the repository and installing it again resolved the issue which i don't really understand but thank you very much for your help!